# React JSX conditional rendering breaks dropdown

Tags: reactjs, jsx, dropdown, conditional-formatting

I've designed a filter component for my app that allows a user to select a method of which to filter through a list of items from a dropdown list. The dropdown options range from text, date and dropdown and only displays the filter method chosen.

I have a JSX expression that lets me swap between the various components based on the filter method. The `text` and `date` options work fine, but the **`dropdown`** filter methods break when inside of the JSX expression (and *only* inside of it). Here's the code for a dropdown filter option called Priority:

```
<select value={priority} onChange={onChange} name="priority">
    <option value="" disabled>
        Filter...
    </option>
    <option value="low">by Low Priority</option>
    <option value="norm">by Normal Priority</option>
    <option value="high">by High Priority</option>
</select>
<label htmlFor="priority">Filtering by Priority Level</label>
```

The conditional formatting follows this format:

```
{ filterType === 'name' ? (
    // Name filter input code
) : filterType === 'date' ? (
    // Date filter input code
) : filterType === 'priority' ? (
    <Fragment>
        <select value={priority} onChange={onChange} name="priority">
            <option value="" disabled>
                Filter...
            </option>
            <option value="low">by Low Priority</option>
            <option value="norm">by Normal Priority</option>
            <option value="high">by High Priority</option>
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="priority">Filtering by Priority Level</label>
    </Fragment>
) : filterType === 'location' && (
    // Location filter input code
)}
```

Again, the `dropdown` snippet of code works just fine outside of the JSX expression, but breaks when added into the JSX expression above.

EDIT: Forgot to include the `Fragment` parent elements needed for JSX expressions. The issue still persists with the parent elements included.

Comment: Can you explain "breaks" means a little more?

Comment: @BrianThompson When the dropdown is placed in the JSX expression, the dropdown form becomes unavailable. Like, unclickable. I can see it in the inspector, CSS doesn't appear to be affecting it and if it's pulled outside of the JSX expression, I can see it/make a selection. Only in the JSX expression does it disable or become unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing that behavior with the snippet below.

If there are any details missing that would lead to your issue please let me know. But as is, it appears to be working.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const types = ['name', 'date', 'priority', ''];

const Example = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [filterType, setType] = useState('');
  
  const onChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value)
  
  const toggleType = () => {
    const lastIndex = types.indexOf(filterType) == types.length - 1 ? -1 : types.indexOf(filterType);
    setType(types[lastIndex + 1])
  }
   
   return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleType}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
      { filterType === 'name' ? (
          <div>Name</div>
      ) : filterType === 'date' ? (
          <div>Date</div>
      ) : filterType === 'priority' ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <select value={value} onChange={onChange} name="priority">
            <option value="" disabled>
              Filter...
            </option>
            <option value="low">by Low Priority</option>
            <option value="norm">by Normal Priority</option>
            <option value="high">by High Priority</option>
          </select>
          <label htmlFor="priority">Filtering by Priority Level</label>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : 
        <div>Else</div>
      }
    </div>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```